# Python scikit learn n_jobs

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, joblib

This is not a real issue, but I'd like to understand:

- running sklearn from Anaconda distrib on a Win7 4 cores 8 GB system
- fitting a KMeans model on a 200.000 samples*200 values table.
- running with n-jobs = -1: (after adding the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line to my script) I see the script starting 4 processes with
  10 threads each. Each process uses about 25% of the CPU (total:
  100%). Seems to work as expected
- running with n-jobs = 1: stays on a single process (not a surprise), with 20 threads, and also uses 100% of the CPU.

My question: what is the point of using n-jobs (and joblib) if the the library uses all cores anyway? Am I missing something? Is it a Windows-specific behaviour?

Comment: with `n_jobs=1` it uses 100% of the cpu of *one of the cores*. Each process is run in a different core. In linux with 4 cores  I can clearly see the cpu usage:`(100%,~5%,  ~5%, ~5%)` when I run `n_jobs=1` and `(100%, 100%, 100%, 100%)` when running with `n_jobs=-1`. Each process takes the 100% usage of a given core, but if you have `n_jobs=1` only one core is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the meantime, I have not been able to reproduce the phenomenon, so I guess it was somehow due to "something" in the state of the machine, or of the notebook.

Comment: Interestingly, I am seeing that H2O (GBM) runs as a single process and utilizes almost 700% CPU on my 8-core machine.

Comment: @Luengo   but it seems OMP_NUM_THREADS can also control the maximum cpu% when using sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV(n_jobs=-1) ...   do you know why? (sklearn is not using OpenMP as I know)

Answer (score 9):

- what is the point of using n-jobs (and joblib) if the the library uses all cores anyway?

It does not, if you specify n_jobs to -1, it will use all cores. If it is set to 1 or 2, it will use one or two cores only (test done scikit-learn 0.20.3 under Linux).

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs) says:

> This parameter is used to specify how many concurrent processes or
>   threads should be used for routines that are parallelized with joblib.
>
> n_jobs is an integer, specifying the maximum number of concurrently
>   running workers. If 1 is given, no joblib parallelism is used at all,
>   which is useful for debugging. If set to -1, all CPUs are used. For
>   n_jobs below -1, (n_cpus + 1 + n_jobs) are used. For example with
>   n_jobs=-2, all CPUs but one are used.
>
> n_jobs is None by default, which means unset; it will generally be
>   interpreted as n_jobs=1, unless the current [joblib.Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html#joblib.Parallel) backend
>   context specifies otherwise.
>
> For more details on the use of joblib and its interactions with
>   scikit-learn, please refer to our [parallelism notes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#parallelism).

Answer (score -2):

You should either use `n_jobs` or `joblib`, don't use both simultaneously.

Comment: can you please explain why?