# How to limit the CPU usage when applying sklearn.Linear_model.LinearRegression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cpu-usage

I need to limit the CPU usage for the following command since it's using 100% of the CPU.

```py
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = True, n_jobs = 1)
    model.fit(df_x0, df_y0)
    model.predict(df_x1)
```

I have set `n_jobs == 1`, and I did not use multiprocessing, but still it kept CPU fully occupied for all kernels and `df_y0`.
`ndim == 1`, I learned that the `n_jobs` would not be effective if so.

Can anyone tell me why it's using 100% of the CPU, and how to solve it in python?

Python 3.7,
Linux.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34416/scikit-learn-n-jobs-parameter-on-cpu-usage-memory

Comment: I have found the solution to it. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8883

Comment: Brilliant.  I also have a specific BLAS library installed, so this is something I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `n_jobs=1` it uses 100% of the CPU of one of the cores. Each process is run in a different core and each process takes the 100% usage of a given core. 
In Linux with 4 cores It can be clearly seen the CPU usage:

- `(100%,~5%, ~5%, ~5%)` when it runs `n_jobs=1`(if you specify `n_jobs` to **1**, **only one core** is used).
- `(100%, 100%, 100%, 100%)` when running with `n_jobs=-1` (if you specify `n_jobs` to **-1**, it will use **all cores**).

also, you can check @kenlukas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287554/10452700) based on his test with scikit-learn 0.20.3 under Linux

**Update:**
To fulfill all scenarios which question [Unintended multithreading in Python (scikit-learn)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124978/10452700) please check out the answers

In case you want to set the number of threads dynamically, and not globally via an environment variable, like:

```py
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(2)
```

Comment: But the truth is, I set n_jobs=1, and it uses all the cores to 100% anyway.  I found the solution to it. It was solved by setting OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1. Thank you.

Comment: @Damon There are probably other options besides `openBLAS` or `MKL` but check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665619/10452700) & [idea behind of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104472/why-would-setting-export-openblas-num-threads-1-impair-the-performance). Check it out the short answer in **Update** if it works for you.