# Parallelize RandomizedSearchCV to restrict number CPUs used

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to limit the number of CPUs' usage when I fit a model using sklearn `RandomizedSearchCV`, but somehow I keep using all CPUs. Following an answer from [Python scikit learn n_jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761556/python-scikit-learn-n-jobs/62131985#62131985) I have seen that in scikit-learn, we can use `n_jobs` to control the number of CPU-cores used.

> `n_jobs` is an integer, specifying the maximum number of concurrently running workers. If 1 is given, no `joblib` parallelism is used at all, which is useful for debugging. If set to -1, all CPUs are used.
> For `n_jobs` below -1, *`(n_cpus + 1 + n_jobs)`* are used. For example with `n_jobs=-2`, all CPUs but one are used.

But when setting `n_jobs` to -5 still all CPUs continue to run to 100%. I looked into [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html#joblib.Parallel) library to use `Parallel` and `delayed`. But still all my CPUs continue to be used. Here what I tried:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from joblib import Parallel,delayed

def rscv_l(model, param_grid, X_train, y_train):
    rs_model = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_grid, n_iter=10,
                            n_jobs=-5, verbose=2, cv=5,
                            scoring='r2')
    rs_model.fit(X_train, y_train)         # the cpu usage problem comes here
    return rs_model

# Here my attempt to parallelize and set my function as iterable
results = Parallel( n_jobs = -5 )( delayed( rscv_l )( model,
                                                      param_grid,
                                                      X, y )
                                                  for X, y
                                             in zip( [X_train],
                                                     [y_train] ) )
```

What is going wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**
Looking at [How do you stop numpy from multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading), I think I might have a multithreading problem. When I inspect numpy configuration I find:

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['user/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['user/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['user/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['user/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['user/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['user/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['user/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['user/include']
```

but still the solutions proposed are not working for me:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"]        = "4" # export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"]   = "4" # export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"]        = "6" # export MKL_NUM_THREADS=6
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "4" # export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS=4
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"]    = "6" # export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=6

import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
```

---

**THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM:**
Thanks to @user3666197 answer, I decided to limit the number of cpus for the whole script and simply use n_jobs with a positive integer. This solved my CPU usage problem:

```
import os
n_jobs = 2  # The number of tasks to run in parallel
n_cpus = 2  # Number of CPUs assigned to this process

pid = os.getpid()
print("PID: %i" % pid)

# Control which CPUs are made available for this script
cpu_arg = ''.join([str(ci) + ',' for ci in list(range(n_cpus))])[:-1]
cmd = 'taskset -cp %s %i' % (cpu_arg, pid)
print("executing command '%s' ..." % cmd)
os.system(cmd)

# hyperparameter tunning
rs_model = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_grid, n_iter=10,
                            n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=2, cv= n_folds,
                            scoring='r2')

#model fitting
rs_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q :** *" What is going wrong?* "

**A :**
There is not a single thing that we can say that it *"goes wrong"*, the code-execution eco-system is so multi-layered, that it is not as trivial as we might wish to enjoy & there are several (different, some hidden) places, where configurations decide, how many CPU-cores will actually bear the overall processing-load.

Situation is also version-dependent & configuration-specific ( both Scikit, Numpy, Scipy have mutual dependencies & underlying dependencies on respective compilation options for numerical packages used )

---

### Experiment
to prove -or- refute a just assumed syntax (d)effect :

Given a documented feature of interpretation of negative numbers in top-level **`n_jobs`** parameter in `RandomizedSearchCV(...)` methods, submit the very same task, yet configured so that it has got explicit amount of permitted (top-level) `n_jobs = CPU_cores_allowed_to_load` and observe, when & how many cores do actually get loaded during the whole flow of processing.

**Results:**
if and only if that very number of "permitted" CPU-cores was loaded, the top-level call did correctly "propagate" the parameter settings to each & every method or procedure used alongside the flow of processing

In case your observation proves the settings were not "obeyed", we can only review the whole scope of all source-code verticals to decide, who is to be blamed for such dis-obedience of not keeping the work compliant with the top-level set ceiling for the `n_jobs`. While O/S tools for CPU-core affinity mappings may give us some chances to "externally" restrict the number of such cores used, some other adverse effects ( the add-on management costs being the least performance-punishing ones ) will arise - thermal-management introduced CPU-core "hopping", being the disallowed by affinity maps, will on contemporary processors cause a more and more reduced clock-frequency (as cores get indeed hot in numerically intensive processing), thus prolonging the overall task processing times, as there are "cooler" (thus faster) CPU-cores in the system (those, that were prevented from being used by the affinity-mapping), yet these are very the same CPU-cores, that the affinity-mappings disallowed from being used for temporally placing our task processing (while the hot ones, from which the flow of the processing was reallocated due to reached thermal-ceilings, got some time to cold down and re-gain the chances to run at not decreased CPU-clock-rates)

Top-level call might have set an `n_jobs`-parameter, yet any lower-level component might have "obeyed" that one value ( without knowing, how many other, concurrently working peers did the same - as in `joblib.Parallel()` and similar constructors do, not mentioning the other, inherently deployed, GIL-evading multithreading libraries - as that happen to lack any mutual coordination so as to keep the top-level set `n_jobs`-ceiling )

```
def rscv_l( model, param_grid, X_train, y_train ):
    rs_model = RandomizedSearchCV( model,
                                   param_grid,
                                   n_iter  = 10,
                                   n_jobs  =  1, # DO NOT CANNIBALISE MORE
                                   verbose =  2, #        AS BEING RUN
                                   cv      =  5, #        IN CONFLICT
                                   scoring = 'r2'#        WITH OUTER-SETTINGS
                                   )             # ----vvv----------
    rs_model.fit( X_train, y_train )             # the cpu usage problem comes here
    return rs_model

################################################################
#
# Here my attempt to parallelize and set my function as iterable
#
results = Parallel( n_jobs = -5 # <------------- joblib spawns that many workers
                    )( delayed( rscv_l ) # <---# HERE, avoid
                              ( model,         #       UNCOORDINATED
                                param_grid,    #       CPU-CANNIBALISM
                                X, y )         #       ref. above
                            for X, y in zip( [X_train],
                                             [y_train] )
                       )
```

---

### If interested in more details

you may also like this
["How to find an optimum number of processes in GridSearchCV( ..., n_jobs = ... )?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183080/how-to-find-an-optimum-number-of-processes-in-gridsearchcv-n-jobs/50186510#50186510)
this
["How does scikit-learn handle..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136430/how-does-scikit-learn-handle-multiple-n-jobs-arguments/59143472#59143472)
and
["How to find ideal number of parallel processes..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532107/how-to-find-ideal-number-of-parallel-processes-to-run-with-python-multiprocessin/60536408#60536408)
from
other [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallel-processing%5D%20is%3Aanswer), covering this problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! After getting inspired by some of your comments I realised I was not delimiting the number of CPU's beforehand. So I decided to limit the number of cpus for the whole script and simply use n_jobs with positive integer. I am still a bit unsure how all interacts, but the updated code in the question description solved my CPU usage problem.

Comment: Glad to see you happy, from using the hints. Be also informed, that common ML-tasks, like .fit()-methods are, are MEMORY-intensive ( so the actual CPU-cache hierarchy sizing, cache-line-lengths and physical, bare-metal, MEM-I/O-channels decide where CPU-starvation starts to happen, no matter how many "free" CPU-cores your computing device is capable of using - the memory blocks and starved CPU-s have but to wait for a free MEM-I/O-channel to fetch any piece of fresh data on cache-miss or on maintaining CPU-cache/RAM coherence, after any data-write ). Anyway, feel free to accept the answer+G/L

Comment: Get inspiration from this answer. Thanks a lot. Just add one comment. For ML tasks on large-scale dataset, it's better to use more CPUs to parallel the ML model itself rather than using more CPU to parallel the RandomizedSearchCV() object. Otherwise, you won't be able to get results for RandomizedSearchCV() even waiting for ages (running RF on large-scale dataset with 1 cpu is  pretty slow)!!!!!  Example code: rf_tree_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=8, verbose=1), param_distributions=random_grid, n_jobs=1, n_iter = 30, cv=3, verbose=10, random_state=42)